# How is Daml able to maintain privacy between the parties if they share the same ledger or from 1.18.0 version postgreSQL?

Tags: daml

How is Daml able to maintain privacy between the parties if they share the same ledger or from the 1.18.0 version of PostgreSQL? Will, that data be visible to all the parties if they are able to access to ledger or PostgreSQL DB?

Answer (score 2):

Good question: in general, the owner and operator of the PostgreSQL instance where you're hosting the ledger will indeed be able to see all of its content. This means that there must be a trust relationship between the operator of the database and the party which is hosting their data there. If a party does not trust any specific operator, they can run their own node. If that's the case, only the data which that party is authorized to see will be on the participant.

Note that, even if multiple parties are hosting their data on the same, trusted node, they will not be able to access each other's data, as the Ledger API only shows to each party the data that it's authorized to access.

Comment: Please can you share more details on, If we want to run a separate node how we will be able to separate our data? How we will be able to map the data to the desired node database through a smart contract?

Also, if one party comes up with their own node but the counterpart still uses the operator's node then also the data will be visible to all the parties if someone anyhow gets access to the database instance? To tackle this do both parties have to create their own nodes?

Comment: The problem with the PostgreSQL-based participant is that it's centralized, but you might be interested in having a look at https://www.canton.io/